# How does "cocurrent" work in a control structure in J?

Tags: j

I was trying this language and I have a question with this code:

```
cocurrent'local1' 
text1=: 'CCC'
cocurrent'local2'
text1=: 'AAA'

f0=: 3 : 0
  select. y
     case. 1   do. text1
     case. 2   do. cocurrent'local1', 'change'
  end.
)

f0 &.> 1 2 1
┌───┬┬───┐
│AAA││AAA│
└───┴┴───┘
```

As you can see, the "change" word never came up, but I call f0 with 2 so the change never happened.

What's going on here?

Comment: @marc_s The function's name is really "cocurrent". "co" is short for "class object".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case 2, you're setting your locale to `'local1change'`, because `'local1', 'change'` concatenates the strings to `'local1change'`.

Also, your last `cocurrent` before `f0` is `local2`, which means `f0` is *inside* `local2`. You're never leaving `local2`. I'm not sure why your last 'AAA' happends though, but know that you should set your current locale with `cocurrent 'base'` (or wherever you started declaring those locales from) before declaring `f0`.

Comment: cocurrent changes are local so the last 'AAA' is from the second `f0 1`.

Comment: @Eelvex so that means the function executes from a locale and any change of locale is only limited to the scope of `f0`? I didn't know. That explains a lot (not just why I try to avoid `cocurrent`).

Comment: The lab 'Locales' followed by the lab 'Object Oriented Programming' give you really good insight into the way the 'co' functions work and why. These labs are found under the Studio menu in the non-console environments of J (any version with a menu interface) Locales are powerful but do require some research to use effectively.

Comment: @MPelletier yes, the change of locale is limited to the scope of `f0`.